# Connect Chargify with firebase

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, chargify

I want to connect chargify with firebase on both android and ios platform. I am not able to find any free tool to do so. Either suggest me some free tool through which i can connect(integrate) chargify with firebase or how can i do the same programmatically ?

Comment: People if you down vote then please mention ways to improve the question also so that it can be improved. Down voting a question wont help

Answer (score 1):

This sounded interesting so I took a quick look.  I think you would integrate with the Chargify API and/or webhooks with a "Cloud Function" as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Unfortunately, this is more of a discussion or exploration than a question, so StackOverflow probably isn't the best place for it and that's why it's getting down-voted. I'd suggest finding a mailing list or forum for Firebase and asking there.